# Countable support iterated forcing of length $\alpha$ which forces $|\alpha| > \aleph_2$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $cf(\alpha) > \omega$, and $P_\alpha := \langle P_{\beta}, \dot{Q}_{\beta} : \beta < \alpha \rangle$  be a countable support iterated forcing construction (so for each $\beta$, $P_{\beta} = P_{\beta - 1} \ast \dot{Q}_{\beta}$ if $\beta$ is a successor ordinal, $P_{\beta} =$ inverse limit of $\langle P_{\gamma} : \gamma < \beta \rangle$ if $cf(\beta) = \omega$, and $P_{\beta} =$ direct limit of $\langle P_{\gamma} : \gamma < \beta \rangle$ otherwise). Let $\Vdash_{P_{\beta}}$ "$\dot{Q}_{\beta}$ is non-trivial", for all $\beta$. What can we specify for the $\dot{Q}_{\beta}$ (and $\alpha$) so that $\Vdash_{P_\alpha} |\alpha| > \aleph_2$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, this will only be possible if $\alpha$ is already at least $\aleph_3$ in the ground model, since forcing can never increase the cardinality of a set. But if $\alpha$ is already that large, then you can achieve your goal with trivial forcing. So have you really asked what you intended?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I missed out on an important point. I require the constituent forcings to be non trivial. What is an easy example to not collapse cardinals between $\omega_{2}^{V}$ and $\alpha$, and which $\alpha$ would work?

Comment: I think the point of the question is that a countable-support proper iteration of length $>\omega_2$ can collapse cardinals (even if the length is only $\omega_2+1$), so the $\aleph_2$ of the extension could be larger than that of the ground model. The OP wants hypotheses that prevent this, or at least prevent $\aleph_2$ from jumping up beyond $|\alpha|$. Unfortunately, even Sacks forcing (which morally "adds a real while doing as little other damage as possible") can collapse cardinals at stage $\omega_2$, so I'm not optimistic about getting a good hypothesis to prevent that.

Comment: You probably want that the $Q_\beta$ (at least most of them) do not add reals. (Necessary, not sufficient.)  If all $Q_\beta$ add reals, then in stage $\kappa+\omega_1$ you will have that $|\kappa|\le\aleph_1$ for all cardinals $\kappa$. In particular, all cardinals $<\alpha$ will have size $\aleph_1$ at most, by the time you reach stage $\alpha$.

Comment: Similarly, you also need that most $Q_\beta$ are $\aleph_2$-c.c., since otherwise you will be generically collapsing the $\aleph_2$ of $V[G_\kappa]$ by stage $\kappa+\omega_1$.

Comment: My non-expert impression is that this question is a good one.  But it would be improved with a gloss on the notation --- at minimum, a sentence reading "I will adopt the notation from [LINK]", or some such.  Motivation and background couldn't hurt, either.

Comment: I was trying to investigate some general pathologies/quirks in iterated forcing, perhaps motivated by what Goldstern mentioned, which I believe was due to Roitman. The length of the iterated forcing having cofinality greater than $\omega$ places a restriction on $2^{\omega}$ in the extension, and very often reals are added so that the length is forced to have cardinality $\leq \aleph_2$. So is $\aleph_2$ a bound, generally speaking? Is there even a bound to $|\alpha|$ in the extension?

I will add some details regarding the notation.

Comment: @Theo, I think the notation used in the question is completely standard, and will be readily understandable to anyone familiar with iterated forcing. Let me add that I find the votes to close this question to be inappropriate.

Comment: Zoorado, you are missing a subscript $\beta$ on $\dot Q$ on the second line.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Fair enough — this is about as far from my expertise as possible. For essentially all MO questions (including set theory and logic questions), I know enough to be able to at least parse the question, whereas this one I cannot, and hence consider it "unclear." $\omega$ is fine, $\alpha$ I assume to be a variable ranging over cardinals, but already I don't know what types of things $c$ and $f$ are (or perhaps $\mathrm{cf}$ is a particular function?). That said, if experts say it makes sense, fine. Anyway, I always prefer MO questions with background and motivation.

Comment: @Theo, in this post, $\alpha$ refers to an ordinal (rather than a cardinal), which will be the length of the forcing iteration, and $\text{cf}(\alpha)$ means the cofinality of $\alpha$, which is the cardinality of the smallest unbounded subset of $\alpha$. Iterated forcing constructions are usually covered in an advanced graduate set theory class, such as Math 235 at Berkeley (or at least that is what it was called 20 years ago). This particular post uses the notation of Kunen's book Set Theory (http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Independence-Studies-Foundations-Mathematics/dp/0444868399).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let each $\dot{Q}_{\beta}$ be $\{f | f : \gamma \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ and $\gamma < \omega_1\}$, ordered by inclusion, as defined in $V[G_{\beta}]$. Let the length of the iteration, $\alpha$, be $> (2^{\omega})^{++}$, with $cf(\alpha) > \omega$. Then $P_{\beta}$ forces $|\dot{Q}_{\beta}| = \aleph_1$ for all $\beta < \alpha$, if CH holds. Now each $\dot{Q}_{\beta}$ is forced to be $\aleph_1$-complete and thus proper. By a theorem of Shelah, $\aleph_1$-completeness of the $\dot{Q}_{\beta}$ means $P_{\alpha}$ has the $\aleph_2$-c.c., if CH holds. But $P_1$ forces CH and forcing with $P_{\alpha}$ is the same as forcing with $P_1$ then with $P_{\alpha}$ defined in $V[G_1]$, since $P_1$ is proper. Thus $P_{\alpha}$ forces $|\alpha| > \aleph_2$.

Comment: Since your forcing is countably closed, it adds no reals, and so you are forcing with $\text{Add}(\omega_1,1)^V$ at each stage $\beta$. Is your overall iteration the same as $\text{Add}(\omega_1,\alpha)$?

Comment: Does $Add(\omega_1, \alpha) = \{f : f$ is a countable partial function from $\omega_1 \times \alpha$ into $\{0, 1\}\}$?.

Comment: Yes, the forcing to add $\alpha$ many Cohen subsets to $\omega_1$.

Comment: I think it is, but I don't have a proof yet. I shall give it some thought later.

Comment: I think it is the same. Your iteration doesn't add reals, and so the iterated forcing construction is really just the same as the product forcing to add $\alpha$ many Cohen subsets to $\omega_1$, which under CH will preserve all cardinals.

Comment: Yes I agree. They are indeed the same.